# Replaced fluorescent tubes and starters - now lights are getting triggered by other light switches. How to identify the cause?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I have two fluorescent tubes in the kitchen. Having been buzzing, flickering and turning themselves off for a while I replaced both the tubes and the respective starters, assuming this would eliminate all variables.

However, now when the lights are on they turn off when flicking light switches in nearby rooms.

Also, the kitchen lightswitch itself gets a bit warm when the lights have been on a few hours.

This never happened before. How can I identify the cause?

Comment: Don't use the lights until you figure out this problem. When you say "starters" do you mean plug-in starters or hard-wired ballasts? What else did you disassemble or rewire during this project?

Comment: @paulmz it was just the [plug-in starters](http://blog.directlight.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Fluorescent-Starter.jpg). I've not disassembled anything just yet. Hoping to to have to and that it's a simple solution before I have to get my tools out.

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure about this one. Does the problem persist if you reinstall the old starters and/or bulbs?